# Angular how to get access to $scope var from modal

Tags: angularjs, scope, modal-dialog

I have a page where I have a button to launch a modal. Both pages has its own controllers. The question is how to get variable from page in modal controller?

Comment: pass the variable in a service and require the service in the modal

Comment: Can you provide some code? Your question is too general

Answer (score 1):

You pass data to your *modal controller* using `resolve`.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    controller: 'MyModalCtrl',
    resolve: {
        variableToPass: function () {
            return $scope.items;
        }
    }
});
```

Then you define your modal controller like this

```
myApp.controller('MyModalCtrl', ['$scope', $modalInstance'', 'variableToPass', function($scope, $modalInstance, variableToPass) {
    ...
}]);
```

Alternatively, or complementary, you can pass the whole `$scope` like this

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    controller: 'MyModalCtrl',
    scope: $scope
});
```